# Why will a Range not work when descending?

Tags: ruby, range

Why will `(1..5).each` iterate over `1,2,3,4,5`, but `(5..1)` will not? It returns the Range instead.

```
1.9.2p290 :007 > (1..5).each do |i| puts i end
1
2
3
4
5
 => 1..5
1.9.2p290 :008 > (5..1).each do |i| puts i end
 => 5..1
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is use downto

```
5.downto(1) do |i| puts i end
```

Comment: And in modern versions of Ruby, you can do `x = 5.downto(1)` and pass `x` around as a variable.

Comment: Nice. a range handles a block as an each iterator automatically. No need to explicitly call `.each`

Comment: [`Numeric#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-step) is a bit more flexible; it also takes a step size, whereas [`Integer#downto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-downto) only takes a limit.

Comment: you can use it with dates too. It's so cool

Answer (score 24):

Ranges use `<=>` to determine if an iteration is over; `5 <=> 1 == 1` (greater-than), so it's done before it starts. Even if they didn't, ranges iterate using `succ`; `5.succ` is `6`, still out of luck. A range's `step` cannot be negative, so that won't work either.

It returns the range because `each` returns what it was called on. Use `downto` if it's the functionality itself you're looking for, otherwise the above answers your actual question regarding "why".

Answer (score 6):

You can easily extend the [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html) class, in particular the *each* method, to make it compatible with both ascending and descending ranges:

```
class Range
   def each
     if self.first < self.last
       self.to_s=~(/\.\.\./)  ?  last = self.last-1 : last = self.last
       self.first.upto(last)  { |i| yield i}
     else
       self.to_s=~(/\.\.\./)  ?  last = self.last+1 : last = self.last
       self.first.downto(last) { |i|  yield i }
     end
   end
end
```

Then, the following code will perform just as you'd expect:

```
(0..10).each  { |i| puts i}
(0...10).each { |i| puts i}
(10..0).each  { |i| puts i}
(10...0).each { |i| puts i}
```

Comment: Nicely coded. A risk when taking this approach is that you may have existing libraries in which the programmer assumed that a backwards range would have no iterations, and by making this change you break that assumption and introduce errors into the library's execution. Imagine that the left and right bounds are represented by variables, x and y, instead of constant Fixnums. In such a case, the programmer might be relying on the "normal" range behaviour. This is a typical risk when monkey-patching a class in Ruby.

Comment: Something like this is what should have been implemented in the ruby-code-base from the start.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't even really have anything to do with Ruby, it's just simple basic math: the range which starts with `5` and ends with `1` is empty. There is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't Ruby go "wait a moment, 1 is less than 5, let's go in reverse instead"?

Comment: ruby is very user-friendly, so it would be entirely reasonable to expect that it would work.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: because Ruby can't tell. The range protocol doesn't require that the right value responds to `<=>`, only the left.

Comment: @gwho: I don't think inventing new incompatible meanings for existing notation is very user-friendly. Everybody who has at least a superficial knowledge of high school level math knows how a range works and would be very surprised by that. Note that this would also require a backwards-incompatible change in the range protocol, because at the moment, the only thing that is required for iterating a range is that the left value responds to `succ` and `<=>`, that is not enough for iterating downwards.

Answer (score 0):

Because Ruby only does what it's told, not what you [mean](http://catb.org/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html).

It can't tell whether you want to go in reverse (ie 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), or whether you really only want the numbers starting from 5 that are less than or equal to 1. It's theoretically possible that someone may want the latter, and because Ruby can't tell what you really want, it'll go with the latter.

Comment: numbers starting from 5 that are less than or equal to 1

Comment: that wasnt very constructive.

Comment: @Hamdan can you explain why my answer isn't constructive? I'm not calling anyone an idiot, I'm just explaining that Ruby doesn't work in the way the OP would expect.

Comment: Because you actually did not explained why.

Comment: @Hamdan what haven't I explained?

Comment: for me, for example, it was creating the iteration path between two sequential type of data, and it works perfectly on increasing the increment, but not decreasing... It's merely a convention that ruby uses. It's not obvious as ruby is most of the times.