# Why does "each"-ing a range only work with incrementing ranges?

Tags: ruby, range, ruby-2.0

This makes absolutely no sense:

```
irb(main):001:0> (1..10).each do |x|
irb(main):002:1*   puts x
irb(main):003:1> end
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
=> 1..10
```

whereas:

```
irb(main):004:0> (10..1).each do |x|
irb(main):005:1*   puts x
irb(main):006:1> end
=> 10..1
```

What's the point in offering a range iterator and support for decrementing ranges if you can't mix and match the two? Is this something fixed in newer versions of ruby? (running windows)

Comment: See @DaveNewton 's explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822764/why-will-a-range-not-work-when-descending).

Comment: Thanks, I've flagged this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Draw a line 20.5cm long line on a piece of paper. Mark off every 0.5cm. Label the markers from -20 to +20. Place your finger on the one marked `10`. How many markers are there to the right that are smaller than `1`? None! The range from 10 to 1 is empty. That's the way it is in maths, that's the way it is intuitively, so that's the way it is in Ruby. Or, if you don't like comparing to maths, then just look at the definition of the `Range` protocol in Ruby: basically `Range#each` means `i = left; while i <= right do i = i.succ; yield i end`. Now think about how often that `while` loop runs.

Comment: In maths the range of a set is the difference between the maximum and minimum members.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that decrementing ranges are not supported. Indeed `10..1` is of class range, but iterating over it produces no results (consider `(10..1).to_a`, an empty list)

Comment: If you do want to achieve what you had hoped ranges would do, you can do `10.downto(1).each { |x| puts x }`

Comment: I just changed to `(1..10).to_a.reverse.each` - is `.downto()` the colloquial preference?

Comment: They both achieve the same thing, but I personally think that the `downto` version states its purpose more clearly.

Comment: Your explanation is inadequate. You are speaking in generalities. You need to dig deeper to understand precisely what `each` does when it is sent to a range `r` for which `r.first > r.last` (ref my comment on your question).

Answer (score 1):

Ranges in Ruby only use for incrementing values. This can be used for numbers

```
(1..5).to_a
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

or even letters

```
('a'..'e').to_a
['a','b','c','d','e']
```

There are other options you could try though. You could do

```
10.downto(1).to_a
```

In Ruby, ranges use the <=> operator to determine if an iteration is over;

```
5 <=> 1 == 1
5 is greater than 1
```

The next value would be 4 which is not greater than 5 but rather less then.

Update: Added explanation

Comment: You have not answered the question. `(5..1).class => Range`. Code monkey wants to know *why* that range responds to `each` in the way that it does.

Comment: OK, I'll see if I can fix the answer